# Huawei update to EMUI 9 broke everything

Tags: google-play-store, huawei, google-play-services

I have a Huawei NOVA 2S which I purchased in China.

I got the EMUI 9 update yesterday and none of my Google Apps were working.
Found this: https://itechify.com/2019/04/26/fix-google-apps-on-huawei-after-emui-9-update/, which is exactly the problem I'm having but those steps don't help.  I ran the GMS installer 1.2 and it removed all google apps.

I then installed Google play services (17.1.22 version code: 17122012).  I keep getting "**Google Play Services won't run unless you update Google Play Services**".  This is the most current version!!

**Another Problem:** I downloaded and installed Chrome from the Chinese app store.  It opens for a minute then crashes.

I can't even get the Play Store to work at all.  I installed the most current version for my architecture from apkmirror.com but it won't work.  It just crashes instantly on opening.

Any suggestions other than use as a paperweight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to rollback to EMUI 8.0.  This was easier than expected through the HiSuite Huawei app for PC.  Click on update/upgrade, then other versions.  It should show you the last version and then click restore.

I then ran GMS installer, and Google-installer-v2 and I'm back in business!  I am still getting "Google Play Services won't run unless you update Google Play Services" occasionally but everything works.